# How do I use GET request for logging with Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Angular JS :

```
// POST Data Works :
    $scope.submit = function(signinfo) {
    $http({
        url :'http://localhost:3000/loginfo',
        method : 'POST',
        data : signinfo
    })
    .then(
        function successCallback(result){
            response = {success: true, data: result}; 
        toastr.success('Successfully Updated');
        toastr.refreshTimer(toastr, 3000);

        $scope.reload();
    },
        function errorCallback(response){
            console.log("Error : " + response.data);
        });
    };


// GET Data Does Not Works : 
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/info')
.then(
    function successCallback(response){
        $scope.signinfo = response.data.info;
    },
    function errorCallback(response){
        console.log("Error : " + response.data)
    });
```

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="loginform()" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid center" name="logform"><br/><br>
<tr ng-repeat="logcred in signinfo"></tr>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label form="emailinput"><b>Email</b></label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="uname" id="emailinput" placeholder="you@example.com" ng-model="username" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label form="pwdinput"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwdinput" placeholder="*******" ng-model="password">
</div>

<a ng-click="reloadPage()" class="navbar-brand" ></a>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="cancel" class="btn" ng-click="toggle_cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</div>
<br/>   
</form>
```

I have created login page form using json and trying to access using `GET` request. I have created 2 form **one for signup and another one for login**.  I have used `POST` for **signing** and its working fine. For **login** I used `GET` request, I thought this would be simple to do but it terribly confusing. I am not sure whether I should use `GET` or `POST` request. I got stuck while writing function for my **login** page.

However, I cannot find a single example. If anyone have any examples they can share?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Post request where you will send UserName and Password.Pass username and password while calling loginform from html file.

HTML File

```
<form ng-submit="loginform(username,password)" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid center" name="logform"><br/><br>
<tr ng-repeat="logcred in signinfo"></tr>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label form="emailinput"><b>Email</b></label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="uname" id="emailinput" placeholder="you@example.com" ng-model="username" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label form="pwdinput"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwdinput" placeholder="*******" ng-model="password">
</div>

<a ng-click="reloadPage()" class="navbar-brand" ></a>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="cancel" class="btn" ng-click="toggle_cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</div>
<br/>   
</form>
```

JS File

```
$scope.loginform = function(username,password){
    $http({
        url :'http://localhost:3000/loginfo',
        method : 'POST',
        data : {
            "userName":username,
            "password":password    
            }
    }).then(
    function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response)
    },
    function errorCallback(response){
        console.log("Error : " + response.data)
    });
}
```

Comment: I have already created the `POST` and it's working fine. What I am actually looking is, when user enter his credentials, username and password should match with json and get login

Comment: The code what you have posted will POST the data , but it wont match with the existing json data

Comment: ok. for that you have to parse json data and then compare with the entered data.

Comment: Actually I tried parsing the data, but i couldn't achieve it. If you have any working example, share it

Comment: I have created plunker. I have uploaded code over there

Answer (score 0):

Use http get request to get data from json file.

```
$http.get('db.json').success(function(response) {
            $scope.data= response;
        });
```